# Angular4 TypeScript JsonReaderException

Tags: c#, .net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I have table with 1 or many records which is displayed to the user. User select one or many checkboxes and submit, when form is submitted data are updated in database. On that moment I'm from code calling location.relaod(); In order to reload page and display correct data.

Here is code from backend web api:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<object> Get()
{
    var entries = await _entryRepository.GetEntriesByUserIdAsync(await GetUserId());

    var result = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Entries>, IEnumerable<EntryReponse>>(entries);

    return Ok(result);
}
```

Here is code of service which is calling web api:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { Entry } from "../models/entry";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class EntryService
{
    private readonly API_URL = 'http://localhost:52841/api/entry/';
    constructor(private http: Http,
        private authService: AuthService) { }


    createEntry(id) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', "Bearer " + this.authService.token);

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(this.API_URL + id, null,options);
    }

    get() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', "Bearer " + this.authService.token);

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.get(this.API_URL,  options).map(res => res.json());
    }

    update(entry: Entry){

        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', "Bearer " + this.authService.token);

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.put(this.API_URL, entry, options);
    }
```

Here is code of component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EntryService } from "../../services/entry.service";
import { MasterCodeService } from "../../services/masterCode.service";
import { SubCodeService } from "../../services/subcode.service";
import { Entry } from "../../models/entry";
import { MasterCode } from "../../models/masterCodes";



@Component({
    selector: 'entry-list',
    templateUrl: './entry-list.component.html'
})
export class EntryListComponent implements OnInit {



    private readonly PAGE_SIZE = 100;


    query: any = {
        pageSize: this.PAGE_SIZE
    };
    masterCodes: any = [];
    subCodes: any = [];
    masterCode: MasterCode = new MasterCode();
    entries: Entry[];
    entry: Entry ={
        id: [],
        masterCodeId: 0,
        subCodeId: 0,
        accepted: 0,
        rejected:0
};


columns = [
        { title: "#" },
        { title: "PO" },
        { title: "SKU" },
        { title: "Status" }
    ];
    constructor(private entryService: EntryService,
        private masterCodeService: MasterCodeService,
        private subCodeService: SubCodeService) {

    }

    load() {
        this.masterCodeService.getMasterCodes(this.query).subscribe(res => {
            this.masterCodes = res;
        });
        this.entryService.get().subscribe(res => {
            this.entries = res;

        });

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.load();


    }

    onChange(event) {
        var selectedMasterCode = this.masterCodes.items.find(x => x.id == event.target.value);
        this.entry.masterCodeId = selectedMasterCode.id;
        this.subCodeService
            .getSubCodes()
            .subscribe(res => this.subCodes = res.filter(x=>x.masterCode.id == selectedMasterCode.id));
    }

    submit(event) {

        if (event.target["noError"]) {

                this.entry.accepted = 0;
                this.entry.rejected = 0;
        }
        if (event.target["accepted"] && event.target["accepted"].checked === true ) {
            this.entry.accepted = 1;
            this.entry.rejected = 0;


        }
        if (event.target["rejected"] && event.target["rejected"].checked === true ) {
            this.entry.accepted = 0;
            this.entry.rejected = 1;
        }


        this.entryService.update(this.entry).subscribe(x => {
            location.reload();
            this.load();
        });
    }

    selectSubCode(event) {
        this.entry.subCodeId = event.target.value;
    }


    onEntryToggle(entryId, $event) {
        if ($event.target.checked)
            this.entry.id.push(entryId);
        else {
            var index = this.entry.id.indexOf(entryId);
            this.entry.id.splice(index, 1);
        }

    }



}
```

After submit is called I'm getting next error:

> > An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing
> >     value: {. Path 'errorMessage', line 1, position 17.
> >     Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers JsonReaderException: Unexpected character
>   encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'errorMessage', line 1,
>   position 17. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType
>   readType) Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader
>   reader, JsonContract contract, bool hasConverter)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(object
>   newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract,
>   JsonProperty member, string id)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
>   object existingValue)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
>   object existingValue)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, bool checkAdditionalContent)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,
>   Type objectType) Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string
>   value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string value,
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance+d__7.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance+d__13.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl+d__10.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl+d__10.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Prerendering.PrerenderTagHelper+d__29.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner+d__0.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   AspNetCore._Views_Home_Index_cshtml+d__12.MoveNext() in
>   Index.cshtml

Please can you give me suggest how I can fix this ?
P.S. Same error I'm getting also if I don't submit form just pres F5 to reload page.

**Update**
Here is JSON on first call:
[image]
[image: From Network panel]

And after reloading:
[image]

Header 1st call:
[image]

Header after reloading:
[image]

What I had understand for some URL paths reloading is working and for some of them is not working. To recap, some of routes can be called manually typed into browser and some of them only calling from links, why ? How I can figure where is mistake if all links, all components, all services are created on same way ?
Kind Regards,
Danijel

Comment: Can you please show us the JSON it's trying to parse?

Comment: I have update question. Just to add, I have put breakpoint on backend when I'm calling GET. On first call it is working, if I try to reload a page, GET is not calling at all.

Comment: Sorry, instead of what you've added, can you instead check the network panel, and add the actual JSON that is being sent to your backend? It needs to be on one of the requests that are failing

Comment: Is it okay now ?

Comment: As I can see difference is in header, on reload it is not calling correct URI.

Comment: Why do you use the "old" and "deprecated" http?

Comment: I don't think that "old" http is creating the problem or it is creating ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had fix with code

```
load() {
    this.entryService.get().subscribe(res => {

        this.entries = res;
},err=>console.log(err));
this.masterCodeService.getMasterCodes(this.query).subscribe(res => {
    this.masterCodes = res;
});



}
```

this was solution for me and to be hones how this help me and why I should add err=>console.log(err) don't know. Would appreciate if someone can clarify me this.

**I was wrong, solution was in app.shared.ts
In routing configuration I had add canActive

{ path: 'entries', component: EntryListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},

Since API is authorized this is mandatory.**